# Are there finitely many trivial stable stems?

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory

One can look up in a table that for example $\pi_4^s = \pi_5^s = 0$.
However, it seems to be that the stable homotopy groups of spheres get larger and larger for higher dimensions.

*Question:* is it known whether all stable stems are nonzero from some stage?

NOTE: a google search results in [a paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26395653) that shows that the 2-primary part of $\pi_{61}^s$ is trivial, which might be helpful.

Comment: I seem to remember that $S^{61}$ is the highest-dimensional sphere without exotic smooth structures. While this doesn't imply that the homotopy groups beyond $61$ are all nontrivial, I know that enumerating these smooth structures is typically done via statements about stable homotopy groups. Perhaps then, $\pi_{61}$ has been proved to be the last vanishing group?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer That is only the case for odd dimensional spheres, and I don’t think it implies the odd stable homotopy groups are nontrivial above 61. This is because what is produced is a exotic sphere that bounds a parallelizable manifold, and these are in the kernel of the map to $coker(J)$.

Comment: Sidenote: all nonstable homotopy groups of $S^3$, $S^4$ and $S^5$ are nontrivial (except obvious ones) https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00952

Comment: Probably the first question to ask is about what is known about the nontriviality of $\operatorname{Ext}_\mathscr{A}(\mathbb{F}_p ,\mathbb{F}_p)$ because these are overestimates of the p torsion of the stable stems.

Comment: What is well understood is that $\pi_i^s$ for $i \equiv 0,1,3,7 \mod 8$ is nontrivial by inspecting the image of the $J$-homomorphism (Adams-Quillen, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/J-homomorphism )